# how to apply where condition on query result in java or jsp

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on **Spring MVC Framework**. i am getting some data via query from server but data is huge. I want to change query like(i want to apply where condition on query result) but i don't want to go back to server after applying `WHERE` condition.

I want to apply `WHERE` condition on query result which is first time loaded?

Is it possible? if is it possible then how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can go for lazy loading data i.e. paging mechanism. If there are lots of data, If possible you can load purticular paging.

Comment: i want to getting whole data in list variable. After put this data in list i want to apply some conditions on list data and show this data on next screen...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to load whole data and base on conditions. It will create no of problem like

- It create performance problem if you load whole data at once.
- Latest Data changes not applied. i.e. it shows a list which you fetched first time. If any data get updated in db it will shown as it managed on client side only.
- Initial loading time increase.

I suggest you should get data by range (pagging) from db every time.